# I am implementing a graph using adjacency list

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int value;
    struct node* next;
} *graph;

int main(void)
{
    int V,E,i,u,v;
    struct node *ptr,*ptr1;
    ptr=malloc(sizeof(struct node *));
    ptr1=malloc(sizeof(struct node *));
    scanf("%d",&V);
    graph=malloc(V*(sizeof(struct node *)));
    if(!graph)
        printf("Not allocated");

    for(i=0;i<V;i++)
    {
        graph[i].next=NULL;
    }

    scanf("%d",&E);
    for(i=0;i<E;i++)
    {
        //printf("**\n");
        scanf("%d %d",&u,&v);
        ptr=malloc(sizeof(struct node *));
        ptr1=malloc(sizeof(struct node *));
        ptr->value=u;
        ptr->next=graph[v].next;
        graph[v].next=ptr;
        ptr1->value=v;
        ptr1->next=graph[u].next;
        graph[u].next=ptr1;
    }

    for(i=0;i<V;i++)
    {

        ptr=graph[i].next;
        printf("**\n");
        printf("%d ===>\n",i);
        while(ptr)
        {
            printf("%d->",ptr->value);
            ptr=ptr->next;
        }
        printf("NULL\n");
    }
}
```

I am getting the following ERROR

a.out: malloc.c:2369: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __
builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)
((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 * (sizeof(size_t)
)) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long)old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing that catches the eye :

```
struct node *ptr,*ptr1;
ptr=malloc(sizeof(struct node *));
ptr1=malloc(sizeof(struct node *));
```

ptr and ptr1 are meant to point to `struct node`s, but you allocate space for a `struct node *`. Same remark for `graph`.

Comment: Thanks. Got my error.
But in some programs "malloc(sizeof(struct node*)) it worked , is there any explanation for that?

Comment: *Undefined behaviour*. C and C++ don't check for memory overflow, so writing too big an object in too small an allocated block just overwrites stuff past it. If you're lucky, the program crashes and you see your error. If you're not, the bug goes unnoticed, until it randomly crashes after another change way later.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure those scanf calls are working? Are you sure the input values are all in range 0 .. V-1?

I'd suggest adding error checking for both of those.

Also those first ptr and ptr1 mallocs are unused.